# Get a value from database and insert into string in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnect.php');


//This function will send the otp
function sendOtp($numberv, $pass){
    //This is the sms text that will be sent via sms
    $sms_content = "Welcome to : Your password is $pass";

    //Encoding the text in url format
    $sms_text = urlencode($sms_content);

    //This is the Actual API URL concatnated with required values
    $api_url = 'xx'

    //Envoking the API url and getting the response
    $response = file_get_contents($api_url);

    //Returning the response
    return $response;
}


//If a post request comes to this script
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //getting username password and phone number.
    $numberv = $_POST['numberv'];

    //Generating a 6 Digits OTP or verification code
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE mobile = '".$numberv."'");
    if($query && $var = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $v = $var['password'];
    $pass = echo $v;
    }


    //Importing the db connection script



    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM otpverify WHERE phone = '".$numberv."' AND verified = '1'");


     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){
         $sql = "INSERT INTO forgotpass (numberv, pass) values ('$numberv','$pass')";
    }

    //If the query executed on the db successfully
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        //printing the response given by sendOtp function by passing the otp and phone number


    }else{
        //printing the failure message in json
        echo 'Failure';
    }

    //Closing the database connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Here i need paste the value in that password string.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have few syntax errors in your code. What is your question? You should not just post your code and expect us to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) doesn't return a string. It return a `mysqli_result`, which you can fetch.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE mobile = '".$numberv."'");
if($query && $var = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $password = $var['password'];
}
```

Comment: This probably means the query has something wrong or couldn't find any result. Can you please try `$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); var_dump($assoc);` and check what you get as result?

Comment: `array(1) {
  ["password"]=>
  string(32) "555fc43d1f5970dcc209f0f002084697"
}`

Comment: i just need only password

Comment: Query is correct. So if you use the code I posted and you try `print_r($password);` just below `$password = $var['password'];` it doesn't print anything?

Comment: So the problem is when you use `$password` variable after this query. You have the password in the variable as expected.

Comment: how to assign print value into $password

Comment: You don't have to assign print value. You already have the password in `$password` variable. How do you use it in your code? Please edit your original post and provide your full code so that I can help you figure out what it's wrong

Comment: actually i keeping pass value in api msg api when i kept any `$password = bb;` its working

Comment: its not working for echo also its just working for print

Comment: 555fc43d1f5970dcc209f0f002084697

Comment: `echo $password;` doesn't provide the same result? Would be useful to see the code.

Comment: Please show the code editing your question above, I can't get further than that with provided information.

Comment: So `$pass = echo $v;` doesn't make sense in PHP. First of all you should replace it with just `echo $v;` and see the result. Than in your code below where you use `$pass` as variable in your INSERT query, replace it with `$v` which should be the variable containing the password.